# App freeze with DispatchSemaphore wait()

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a function getFriends that reads a User's friendlist from firestore and puts each friend in a LocalUser object (which is my custom user class) in order to display the friendlist in a tableview. I need the DispatchSemaphore.wait() because I need the for loop to iterate only when the completion handler inside the for loop is called.
When loading the view, the app freezes. I know that the problem is that semaphore.wait() is called in the main thread. However, from reading DispatchQueue-tutorials I still don't understand how to fix this in my case. 
Also: do you see any easier ways to implement what I want to do?

This is my call to the function in viewDidLoad():

```
    self.getFriends() { (friends) in
        self.foundFriends = friends
        self.friendsTable.reloadData()
    }
```

And the function getFriends:

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    func getFriends(completion: @escaping ([LocalUser]) -> ()) {
    var friendsUID = [String : Any]()
    database.collection("friends").document(self.uid).getDocument { (docSnapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error:", error!)
            return
        }
        friendsUID = (docSnapshot?.data())!
        var friends = [LocalUser]()
        let friendsIdents = Array(friendsUID.keys)

        for (idx,userID) in friendsIdents.enumerated() {
            self.getUser(withUID: userID, completion: { (usr) in
                var tempUser: LocalUser
                tempUser = usr
                friends.append(tempUser)
                self.semaphore.signal()
            })
            if idx == friendsIdents.endIndex-1 {
                print("friends at for loop completion:", friends.count)
                completion(friends)
            }
            self.semaphore.wait()
        }
    }
}
```

friendsUID is a dict with each friend's uid as a key and true as the value. Since I only need the keys, I store them in the array friendsIdents. Function getUser searches the passed uid in firestore and creates the corresponding LocalUser (usr). This finally gets appended in friends array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should almost never have a semaphore.wait() on the main thread. Unless you expect to wait for < 10ms.

Instead, consider dispatching your friends list processing to a background thread.  The background thread can perform the dispatch to your database/api and wait() without blocking the main thread.

Just make sure to use DispatchQueue.main.async {} from that thread if you need to trigger any UI work.

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

func getFriends(completion: @escaping ([LocalUser]) -> ()) {
    var friendsUID = [String : Any]()
    database.collection("friends").document(self.uid).getDocument { (docSnapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error:", error!)
            return
        }


    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        friendsUID = (docSnapshot?.data())!
        var friends = [LocalUser]()
        let friendsIdents = Array(friendsUID.keys)

        for (idx,userID) in friendsIdents.enumerated() {
            self.getUser(withUID: userID, completion: { (usr) in
                var tempUser: LocalUser
                tempUser = usr
                friends.append(tempUser)
                self.semaphore.signal()
            })
            if idx == friendsIdents.endIndex-1 {
                print("friends at for loop completion:", friends.count)
                completion(friends)
            }
            self.semaphore.wait()
        }
        // Insert here a DispatchQueue.main.async {} if you need something to happen
        // on the main queue after you are done processing all entries
    }
}
```