# how to fix app freeze after dispatchsemaphore call

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async, dispatchsemaphore

I was reading up on [this question about app freezes and semaphores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949543/app-freeze-with-dispatchsemaphore-wait) and I tried to implement the answer into my code, but it still freezes my app despite calling the UI work on the main thread. My goal is to stop the app from freezing once all the entries are called and have the UI work continue like normal.

This is the alert action I have in the deletion method so far:

```
let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { (deletion) in
            let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
            
            
            self.deleteButton.isHidden = true
            self.loadingToDelete.alpha = 1
            self.loadingToDelete.startAnimating()
            
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                self.db.collection("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        print("The docs couldn't be retrieved for deletion.")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    guard querySnapshot?.isEmpty == false else {
                        print("The user being deleted has no events purchased.")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        let docID = document.documentID
                        
                        self.db.collection("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought/\(docID)/guests").getDocuments { (querySnap, error) in
                            guard querySnap?.isEmpty == false else {
                                print("The user being deleted has no guests with his purchases.")
                                return
                            }
                            
                            for doc in querySnap!.documents {
                                let guest = doc.documentID
                                self.db.document("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought/\(docID)/guests/\(guest)").delete { (error) in
                                    guard error == nil else {
                                        print("Error deleting guests while deleting user.")
                                        return
                                    }
                                    print("Guests deleted while deleting user!")
                                    semaphore.signal()
                                }
                                semaphore.wait()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                self.db.collection("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        print("There was an error retrieving docs for user deletion.")
                        return
                    }
                    guard querySnapshot?.isEmpty == false else {
                        return
                    }
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        let docID = document.documentID
                        
                        self.db.document("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought/\(docID)").delete { (err) in
                            guard err == nil else {
                                print("There was an error deleting the the purchased events for the user being deleted.")
                                return
                            }
                            print("Purchases have been deleted for deleted user!")
                            semaphore.signal()
                        }
                        semaphore.wait()
                    }
                }

                
                self.db.document("student_users/\(user.uid)").delete(completion: { (error) in
                    
                    guard error == nil else {
                        print("There was an error deleting the user document.")
                        return
                    }
                    print("User doc deleted!")
                    semaphore.signal()
                })
                semaphore.wait()
                
                user.delete(completion: { (error) in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        print("There was an error deleting user from the system.")
                        return
                    }
                    print("User Deleted.")
                    semaphore.signal()
                })
                semaphore.wait()
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.loadingToDelete.stopAnimating()
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.Segues.studentUserDeletedAccount, sender: self)
                }
            }
        }
```

So this actually deletes everything cleanly with no residual data in the Firestore database, which is what I wanted to happen all along, the only issue is that the app freezes. I thought that the answer in the question I linked above would work in my case, but it didn't.

Also to mention, I've had suggestions of using Cloud Functions for this issue but my app has two types of users with different logic and syntax in the deletion process so I couldn't just use a simple `auth().onDelete()` in Cloud Functions and clean up residue. Even if I could, it would be the same issue I'm facing here but just on the server side, trying to order the tasks correctly, which in my opinion is repetitive and not the most sensible thing to do at this point.

Any other suggestions to overcome this issue? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** Since semaphores are **not** the way to go, I resorted to this :

```
let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { (deletion) in
            
            
            self.deleteButton.isHidden = true
            self.loadingToDelete.alpha = 1
            self.loadingToDelete.startAnimating()
            
                self.db.collection("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        print("The docs couldn't be retrieved for deletion.")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    guard querySnapshot?.isEmpty == false else {
                        print("The user being deleted has no events purchased.")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        let docID = document.documentID
                        
                        self.db.collection("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought/\(docID)/guests").getDocuments { (querySnap, error) in
                            guard querySnap?.isEmpty == false else {
                                print("The user being deleted has no guests with his purchases.")
                                return
                            }
                            let group = DispatchGroup()
                            for doc in querySnap!.documents {
                                let guest = doc.documentID
                                group.enter()
                                self.db.document("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought/\(docID)/guests/\(guest)").delete { (error) in
                                    guard error == nil else {
                                        print("Error deleting guests while deleting user.")
                                        return
                                    }
                                    print("Guests deleted while deleting user!")
                                    group.leave()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                self.db.collection("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        print("There was an error retrieving docs for user deletion.")
                        return
                    }
                    guard querySnapshot?.isEmpty == false else {
                        return
                    }
                    let group = DispatchGroup()
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        let docID = document.documentID
                        group.enter()
                        self.db.document("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought/\(docID)").delete { (err) in
                            guard err == nil else {
                                print("There was an error deleting the the purchased events for the user being deleted.")
                                return
                            }
                            print("Purchases have been deleted for deleted user!")
                            group.leave()
                        }
                    }
                }
            
            self.db.collection("student_users").whereField("userID", isEqualTo: user.uid).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                guard error == nil else {
                    print("There was an error deleting the user document.")
                    return
                }
                guard querySnapshot?.isEmpty == false else {
                    return
                }
                let group = DispatchGroup()
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let docID = document.documentID
                    group.enter()
                    self.db.document("student_users/\(docID)").delete { (err) in
                        guard err == nil else {
                            return
                        }
                        print("User doc deleted!")
                        group.leave()
                    }
                }
            }
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            group.enter()
                user.delete(completion: { (error) in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        print("There was an error deleting user from the system.")
                        return
                    }
                    print("User Deleted.")
                    group.leave()
                })
                
            group.notify(queue: .main) {
                
                self.loadingToDelete.stopAnimating()
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.Segues.studentUserDeletedAccount, sender: self)
            }
         
        }
```

This still leaves residual data and does not execute the tasks in order. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Cloud Functions don't have to be called from a trigger. You can explicitly call them and pass information to them. And, as someone pointed out in one of your past questions, using `async/await` (which Swift doesn't have quite yet) might greatly simplify ordering the tasks.

Comment: So you're telling me there's no way to solve this on client side at all? I'm pretty much at the pinnacle of solving this so it would suck to have to start all over and try to learn some syntax on the server side. @jnpdx

Comment: I did not say it can't be solved on the client side. You gave a reason in your question that you believed it couldn't be done server side, which I believe is incorrect, so I was trying to explain that there's an option to do it server side.

Comment: If you insist on performing this task client side then I would urge against the use of a semaphore because it's not necessary and they should be used very sparingly. If you have a bunch of async tasks that you want to give a completion handler to then use Dispatch Groups. You can also keep a list of document references whenever the user creates new documents and then just delete everything on that list when it comes time to delete a user. But in this particular use case, just use nested dispatch groups and execute one task after the other and perform the segue on the final one.

Comment: You can create a boolean variable to track any errors along the way and when it gets to the final completion handler, rerun the task automatically if the variable is `true`. But the best form of recursion would be to finish the task when the database queries return error-free snapshots that are empty. When the final query shows nothing then finish the task. But I would avoid semaphores here.

Comment: I want the tasks executed in a specific order, the order in my code snippet above, isn't DispatchGroup for when you don't care about the order the tasks are executed in? @bxod

Comment: You can maintain order if you use multiple dispatch groups. When you query the database and get back a bunch of documents and then loop through those documents, a dispatch group can simply give that loop its own completion handler. So when that loop concludes and the final async call finishes, you can then move to the next task (and repeat, if necessary, with another dispatch group). As long as you start the next task in the completion of the previous task, order is never broken.

Comment: what do you mean by multiple? multiple declarations of dispatchgroup in each firestore query completion handler or multiple `group.enter()` and `group.leave()` blocks? I will update my post to show you what I have so far so we're both on the same page. @bxod

Comment: Multiple instances of dispatch group.

Comment: Okay, I'm still having trouble and maybe didn't comprehend what you meant in your last paragraph, would I also have multiple `group.notify()` calls as well, or just one final one after all the tasks? Currently I have one `group.notify()` on the last instance of dispatch group, but the order of the tasks are still incorrect when the alert action gets triggered. @bxod

Comment: What do you mean by your revision that says “leaves residual data”? In regards to them not being in order, that’s good, as it means that you’re enjoying concurrency (which will make it go faster). So collect the results in some local, order-independent structure (such as a dictionary) and then re-order them before updating you model object.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you some ideas because I think your solution should incorporate some or all of these. First is how dispatch groups work and how you can nest them to execute blocks of async tasks in order:

```
func deleteUser(completion: @escaping (_ done: Bool) -> Void) {
    // put UI into loading state
    
    db.collection("someCollection").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let snapshot = snapshot {
            if snapshot.isEmpty {
                completion(true) // no errors, nothing to delete
            } else {
                let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup() // instantiate the group outside the loop
                var hasErrors = false
                
                for doc in snapshot.documents {
                    dispatchGroup.enter() // enter on every iteration
                    
                    db.document("someDocument").delete { (error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print(error)
                            hasErrors = true
                        }
                        
                        dispatchGroup.leave() // leave on every iteration regardless of outcome
                    }
                }
                
                dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                    if hasErrors {
                        completion(false) // failed to delete
                    } else {
                        // execute next task and repeat
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                completion(false) // failed to delete
            }
        }
    }
}

deleteUser { (done) in
    if done {
        // segue to next view controller
    } else {
        // retry or alert user
    }
}
```

The example above is the basics of how dispatch group can work for you. When you leave the group the same number of times you've entered it, the completion handler is called. This example does not have any recursion and doesn't check if everything was actually deleted. Here is an example of how you could add some of that:

```
func deleteUser(completion: @escaping (_ done: Bool) -> Void) {
    var retries = 0
    
    func task() {
        db.collection("someCollection").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let snapshot = snapshot {
                if snapshot.isEmpty {
                    completion(true) // done, nothing left to delete
                } else {
                    // delete the documents using a dispatch group or a Firestore batch delete
                    
                    task() // call task again when this finishes
                           // because this function only exits when there is nothing left to delete
                           // or there have been too many failed attempts
                }
            } else {
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
                retries += 1 // increment retries
                run() // retry
            }
        }
    }

    func run() {
        guard retries < 5 else {
            completion(false) // 5 failed attempts, exit function
            return
        }
        if retries == 0 {
            task()
        } else { // the more failures, the longer we wait until retrying
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(retries)) {
                task()
            }
        }
    }
    
    run()
}
```

This doesn't answer your question directly but it should help you with the task overall. You can also forego some of the looping and deleting and do it all inside a Firestore batch operation, which comes with its own completion handler. There are lots of ways to tackle this but these are some things I'd consider.

Comment: One more thing I had a question about, since in my code snippet I have multiple queries, should I put all of those queries into one big `deleteUser` method like you have in your answer or should I make smaller methods which each query and then order the method calls in the alert action closure? @bxod

Comment: @dante I would suggest that you choose what is easiest to read and understand (by other developers) and putting them into one big function or piecing them out is entirely preference and what you consider easier to read. Personally, I think I'd have a main function called `deleteUser()` which may contain smaller functions within it for clarity. And whatever you choose, I would also suggest that you be consistent. However you normally do things throughout the app is probably how you should continue to do them here. Consistent code is easier to read.

Comment: yeah i won't lie man, I can't even understand it myself let alone other developers, I'm still running into issues and getting infinite recursive printing when trying to call the function on deletion. I'm gonna make another post to discuss the issue over there instead cause this is just the most frustrating thing I've had to deal with. @bxod

Comment: @dante Sketch it out on a piece of paper of what exactly you want done and in what order you want them done in. Simplify this thing as much as possible. What you are trying to do is simple and straight forward but it can be frustrating if you're trying to fix it from the middle. My suggestion is to start this task over from the very start. Start with the parent function `deleteUser()` and do nothing but code out the recursion steps. Test it in Playground and make sure it works. Do everything in Playground piece by piece.

Comment: @dante you need to think like a caveman right now. When the user taps the delete button, what happens? Is the UI frozen? If it's frozen, freeze the UI. Then what? Then you need to fetch the user's purchases, so do that. Then what? Then we go through those purchases and delete them one by one. Or maybe we just collect those document references in an array perhaps and at the very end, run a Firestore batch operation and delete them atomically (all at once, all or none). If the batch fails, retry it. Before you even write any code, map this out on paper and keep it incredibly simple.

Comment: Check my newest question, don't think there's a need for all of that. @bxod